# SSRS: Action on click tablix fields

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

Given a tablix on a ssrs report is it possible to vahe the "Action" property of a cell  (Text Box properties >>> Action) to change depending of the value in that field. To pe more explicit If the tablix's dataset return eg 5 rows I want a different action on click for each row based on the actual value in the field for that returned row. AL I managed until now is to have an action for that field no matter on which row I click

Comment: Not clear what you are asking ? Can you give sample or example ?

Comment: I have a table in a SSRS report (tablix it's called). when I right click a cell in the tablix a "TextBox Properties" link is available and from here to the "Action" tab of the "TextBox properties". In the "Action" tab I check "Go to report" option. Next to the "Specify report" there is a "fX" button which leads to expression window. I need an expression that will call a different report depending on the value of a specific field

Comment: What values that would be thats what I am asking ??

Comment: row value of field ... you assumed right ... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what values you want to use so I am assuming you want to change the report depending on the  row value of one field. For that purpose you can write the expression as,

```
  =IIF(Fields!YourFieldtoCheck.Value = "valuetocheck","Report Name 1","Report Name 2")
```

To use switch you can do as,

```
=SWITCH(Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Low", "yourreport1",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Moderate", "yourreport2",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Medium", "yourreport3",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "High", "yourreport4",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Very High", "yourreport5"
)
```

Comment: small comment here. with this expr I checked sucesfully for row value of one row and every other values in rows goes to the report specified in the "FALSE" part of the "IIF". Is there in SSRS expressions an equivalent of the "CASE" statement in TSQL or like the SWITCH in C# ... like IF value1 then elseis value2 then ... and so on? The IIF function allows for one TRUE and one FALSE